# WCF REST Service (self-hosted) accessible only in local network (and must be accessed remotely)

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-rest, self-hosting

I have a self-hosted REST service (in C#) which works perfectly in my local network, but is unreachable remotely. Here is my hosting code:

```
static Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://m.y.i.p:8080");
WebServiceHost serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(WebService.RestService),
    baseAddress);
serviceHost.Open();
```

(Which is run in Windows Forms, BTW).

Here is App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
</bindings>
<services>
    <service name="WebService.RestService" behaviorConfiguration="Default">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" 
          behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" 
          contract="WebService.ICarga">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Default">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

When, in a browser, I enter 10.1.1.1:8080/test, it shows exactly what I want. But when I type m.y.i.p:8080/test, it is unreachable. Firewall is off, I'm running as administrator and already tried the netsh command. Port 8080 is correctly forwarded to my PC. How can I make this accessible remotely?

Thanks.

EDIT:
For people looking into this in the future, I had a problem with my router (my ip changed, and I didn't change it in the router). Everything should work if you define your App.config right. If you have this problem, double check your code, be sure that your network is working the way you expect it to, if needed turn off firewall and if you're not administrator, use the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531375/wcf-service-self-hosting-service-does-not-work) or [this MS page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx) to own your desired port.

Comment: this sounds more like a problem with DNS

Comment: I guess it is not DNS, because before these tests, I used the same port for Apache and it worked (of course I'm not using Apache now).

Comment: there is not enough information to help... check the event log...

Comment: That is the problem... Nothing is shown in the event log, like no connection was made.

Comment: In fact, it was a problem on the router. +1 for making me look into it... Sorry for this...

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
new Uri("http://m.y.i.p:8080");
```

to

```
new Uri("http://0.0.0.0:8080");
```

Comment: +1 as this will help me now that I know I don't need to set the IP in every PC I'll use my program.